# What is the iOS securecoding feature, and what risks does it mitigate?

Tags: appsec, mobile, source-code, code-review

iOS 6 and newer allows for developers to implement a secure coding method that seems to prevent impostor objects from being de-serialized

Can anyone [explain what this would actually protect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSSecureCoding_Protocol_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/NSSecureCoding/supportsSecureCoding) to the layman?